# How to seque a subclass of UITableViewCell?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I've created a subclass of *UITableViewCell*. Until now, I've only been using cells which is "designed" in my storyboard where I can setup segues.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    [super prepareForSegue:segue sender:sender];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showNews"]) {
        NewsViewController *newsViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        News *news = (News*)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        newsViewController.news = news;
    }
}
```

After I've created my subclass of *UITableViewCell* I'm no longer able to use the Storyboard to create segues for the custom cell, right? I've tried to create a cell in the storyboard and set its class to my custom class -- but then the cell is just blank when I run the App.

So instead I'm just alloc and init the custom cell in my `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"WSTableViewCell";

    WSTableViewCell *cell = (WSTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[WSTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    WSObject *item = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.titleLabel setText:item.title];

    return cell;
}
```

Then in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` I'm trying to creating the NewsViewController, setting the news item and push it to the navigationController:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    News* news = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NewsViewController *newsViewController = [[NewsViewController alloc] init];
    newsViewController.news = news;
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:newsViewController animated:YES];
}
```

But when I select a row my NewsViewController is not shown -- but instead I see a blank view with a black background. How can I deal with this? Is it possible to still use seques?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem I think is that you are using `alloc-init` to instantiate `NewsViewController`. That does not create your `NewsViewController` from storyboard. You have to use `[UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier]` to instantiate from storyboard.

However, I think the easier way is to call

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showNews" sender:indexPath]
```

in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. You have to change your `prepareForSegue...` a little bit.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = (NSIndexPath *)sender;

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showNews"]) {
        NewsViewController *newsViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        News *news = (News*)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        newsViewController.news = news;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why isn't the `super` call needed?

Comment: You mean `[super prepareForSegue:...]`? I think you don't have to do that b/c `UIViewController`'s implementation does not do anything. If you are subclassing your own `UIViewController` subclass and want to use its `prepareForSegue` implementation as well, you have to call `super` at that time.